# React Native Websocket handle message from another component

Tags: javascript, websocket, react-native

I'm trying to build a messaging app. App logs in using user's credentials and starts a websocket connection and gets presence informations. What I wish to do is, when user is actively chatting to another and a presence status of some other user changes, user should able to see him go offline when he comes back to main component.

Users are being listed in main component, and after clicking one item it navigates to chat component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used events to communicate between components even though its not recommended by React-Native developers. I simply imported [*react-native-simple-events*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-events) and followed its examples. Another solution might be using navigator.replace() to pass new router data, I haven't tested it yet though.